# How to add toggle button to AutoCAD ribbon using .NET development?

Tags: c#, .net, api, autocad, autodesk

There is a toggle button in AutoCAD's default ribbons, but I don't know how to add it to AutoCAD using C# (or any other programming language).

[image: sample of toggle button in autocad]

Answer (score 1):

I myself found the answer to this question by trial and error. In fact, Autodesk itself has a class for toggle buttons.
Instead of adding a normal button, you can add a toggle, which will be as follows.

```
Autodesk.Windows.RibbonToggleButton btn = new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonToggleButton();

    btn.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;
    btn.Text = "Buttom Title";
    btn.Name = "Name";
    srcPanel.Items.Add(btn);
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a custom Toggle Button on CUI Ribbon.

https://github.com/MadhukarMoogala/SimpleToggleButton